# How to refresh a sqlite row id when an ImageButton is clicked inside a ListView item in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I have a listview based on a simple cursor adapter.

My custom listview item has a TextView and an ImageButton.

When I select a listview item and I go to a different activity named B.

So far everything works well.
When I click my ImageButton I get my different activity B with the same data for a different listview item.

Only when I select initially a different ListView Item I get my different activity B with the proper data.
Somewhere it keeps the same id, **so how I am going to refresh the id when the ImageButton is clicked?**

The Adapter is

```
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

    TextView tmName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTeamName);
    tmName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1))));

    TextView tmOp  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTeamOpponent);
    tmOp.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(2))));

    TextView tmDate  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTeamDate);
    tmDate.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(3))));

    TextView tmVe  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTeamVenue);
    tmVe.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(4))));


    ImageButton Edit = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imgEdit);
    Edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            String new_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(0)));

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, PlayerActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("TID", new_id); 
            myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });

    view.setTag(cursor.getPosition());
}
```

Comment: in the onClickListener just call the cursor method, cursor.moveToPosition(); read the doc, basically u will be moving the cursor to the clicked position. Rest of ur code should work fine mostly, if it does not. let me know. I'll be happy to help.

Comment: I do before String new_id... cursor.moveToPosition(cursor.getPosition()); but nothing has changed from before

Comment: paste this code above the onClickListener: 
final int position = cursor.getPosition();

After that, in the onClickListener paste: 

cursor.moveToPosition(position);

Comment: I have tried that and position=1 all the time

Comment: could you paste your full code over here? maybe use the getView instead of the bind view?

Answer (score 0):

```
int position=(Integer)view.getTag();
cursor.moveToPosition(position);
```

is the proper way